# KonvaJs Group's hide() or show() methods do not affect the visibility of its children

Tags: javascript, konvajs, group, konva

i have created a group in konvaJs
`ShoulderPatternGroup = new Konva.Group();`
Then, I added some shapes to it such as circles and lines:

```
var circle = new Konva.Circle({
    x: stage.getRelativePointerPosition().x,
    y: stage.getRelativePointerPosition().y,
    radius: 3,
    stroke: '#DCF2F1',
    strokeWidth: 2,
    draggable: true,
});
ShoulderPatternGroup.add(circle);
```

In another function, after calling `ShoulderPatternGroup.hide()` or `ShoulderPatternGroup.show()`, the visibility of the group changes but it does not affect its children (circles and lines).

What is wrong with my code?

i want to disappear all of group elements after calling .hide() and show them after calling .show()

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and improve your question. Ideally make a minimal code snippet in the question that shows the problem. By the way, you have a bug - check your assumptions and walk through the code. Group hide/show works preceisely as you expect.